# Meaning of "Die Reisenden, die in die DDR zurückkehren wollen, müssen mit Westgeld ausgestattet werden."

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

From *Der Spiegel*:

> Auch das zweite Problem *(von einem Gesetzentwurf über Reisen ins Ausland)* hat es in sich: Sollen die Reisenden, die in die DDR zurückkehren wollen, nicht auf die Barmherzigkeit ihrer Gastgeber angewiesen sein, müssen sie mit Westgeld ausgestattet werden. Doch Devisen sind in der DDR so rar wie Bananen. Die Experten rechnen durch, wie viel es kosten würde, wenn man die entsprechenden Auslansreiseregelungen der sozialistischen Bruderländer übernehmen würde.

I don't understand why people who want to come back to the DDR (*Reisenden, die in die DDR zurückkehren wollen*) need to be provided with western money. If they're coming back to the DDR, shouldn't they need DDR money?

Comment: Dein Problem ist kein sprachliches, Du hast den Satz völlig richtig verstanden. Sicher brauchen alle DDR-Bürger, die in der Westen reisen wollen, Westgeld. Die, die dort bleiben wollen, sind aus DDR-Sicht ohnehin verloren und können ignoriert werden. Die Sorge gilt daher denen, die reisen und zurückkehren wollen.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Ach so. Können die Reisenden nicht ihr Ostgeld mitbringen und das später im Westen ins Westgeld umtauschen?

Comment: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_(DDR)

Comment: Offiziell war Ein- und Ausfuhr der Ost-Mark verboten.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about history rather than the German language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The refernce is not the return to the GDR, but the initial journey to the BRD,i.e. more completely the sentence would read

> "Sollen die Reisenden, die (zunächst von der DDR in die BRD reisen wollen und anschließend) in die DDR zurückkehren wollen, ..., müssen (vor ihrer Reise von der DDR in die BRD) mit Westgeld ausgestattet werden"

I assume that When *you* travel to a foreign country, you  can

- pay with your credit card
- withdraw local currency from your home bank account at the travel destination
- exchange your home currency at a local exchange office at the travel destination
- exchange your home currency to target currency at a bank in your home country
- pay directly with your home currency
- pay with a much-respected third-country currencies (such as USD or EUR)

None of these would have been feasible for a GDR citizen, mostly because western currency was too valuable for the GDR to hand out and GDR currency practically worthless in western countries.

Comment: One should add that the issue did not exist in the same way for those who did not want to return. They could count on initial support from BRD authorities and general solidarity from West German citizens. From a DDR point of view they were traitors who were wasting their expensive socialist education by donating it to a capitalist regime, so the DDR regime had no interest whatsoever in providing them with western currencies. But those who wanted to return were valuable members of socialist society and represented their state while in the west. One could not allow them to appear as paupers.

Answer (score 1):

> Reisende, die in die DDR zurückkehren wollen

betont etwas, was normalerweise selbstverständlich wäre: daß jemand von einer Reise in seine Heimat zurückkehrt. Im Kontext ist es aber überhaupt keine Selbstverständlichkeit, denn sicher hätten viele DDR-Bürger dieses Gesetz genutzt, um dauerhaft in die BRD *aus*zureisen. Diejenigen aber, die tatsächlich eine "normale" Reise unternehmen wollten, brauchten eben Geld, um ihre Reiseausgaben (Unterkunft, Verpflegung usw.) zu bezahlen. Hier kam erschwerend hinzu, dass DDR-Bürgern der Besitz von D-Mark offziell sogar verboten war. Die DDR-Mark war aber nicht frei in D-Mark tauschbar, und wie das Zitat betont, die DDR verfügte bei weitem nicht über genügend D-Mark-Bestände bzw. -Quellen, um auf einem eigenen "Markt" einen solchen Umtausch zu organisieren.

> why people who want to come back to the DDR ... need to be provided with western money?

Die Frage zeigt, dass die Formulierung etwas unglücklich und mißverständlich ist. Der Verweis auf die Absicht zur Rückkehr dient allein der Abgrenzung der Personengruppe zu den Ausreisewilligen. Die Frage der Ausstattung mit Westgeld hingegen betrifft nicht die Rückreise, sondern stellt sich natürlich vor Antritt der Reise. Das erschließt sich aber nicht eindeutig aus der Formulierung, sondern aus der (vom Autor vorausgesetzten) Kenntnis der historischen Gegebenheiten.

Answer (score -2):

So if you wanted to visit the GDR, from West Germany, you had to exchange a certain amount of money every day. On leaving the GDR you could not take your GDR money ("Ostmark") with you. That was not allowed.

The same was true for citizens of the GDR. They could not travel with GDR-currency. Therefore whenever they in rare case were allowed to travel to the West the GDR would have to provide them some Western currency (DM). This of course was not really practible because sources of West German currency were limited for the GDR then.

One source of Western currency was the exchange from people entering the GDR which was done at a rate of 1:1, i.e. 1 DM (West German currency) for 1 M (GDR currency) but the rate back was 15:1, i.e. you needed 15 M (or more GDR currency) for one 1 DM (West German currency). On the black market you could get a rate of up to 5:1 however. So you entered the GDR and you lost 14 DM every day because you could not take the money back out again and had to echxange it there at a rate of 15:1.

It was a win win for the GDR government to get hold of Western currency ("Westdevisen"). But it is clear that they wanted to keep the currency, and not give it to people traveling outside of the GDR. Hence it was a problem which is noted in the following sentence:

> Sollen die Reisenden [...] nicht auf die Barmherzigkeit ihrer Gastgeber angewiesen sein, müssen sie mit Westgeld ausgestattet werden.

The ommited part

> die in die DDR zurückkehren wollen

further specifies what travelers were meant here, i.e. those who plan to come back to the GDR (and not those many who left the GDR forever).

Comment: Down voted for the spelling errors, word usage (you don't swap money, you exchange it), not distinguishing properly between East and West Germany (DDR was Germany, too), and the nonsense of the DDR government "creating DM".

Comment: And the suggested exchange rate 1:15 is also pure fantasy. It was rather 1:5 (inofficially, of course) in the years before the wall came down.

Comment: @Robert: such errors should be edited - that's why we are a community driven site.

Comment: As it stands now, the answer still deals with currency regulations for travellers from West to East Germany. The question, however, deals with a legislative initiative in autumn 1989 for travels in the opposite direction and the financial implications it would have. So this is not an answer, but rather a comment.

Comment: @Takkat Yes, but why edit a text full of errors that doesn't even answer the question?

Comment: @Matthias: IMO the question is on history rather than on German language anyway as understanding the text involves knowledge of political circumstances in the GDR. This is addressed in all answers here - no answer gives a language advice. Therefore I can't see why this answer here should be treated differently (at least not after editing English language weaknesses).

Comment: @Takkat Well, at least the two other answers tried to address language aspects that might have made the original quote harder to understand. And I think there is still a difference between a post that tries to answer the question as it stands (off-topic or not) and a post that doesn't, and not even tries to.

Comment: @Takkat Agreed, and I started editing, but it was just too much. At some point you can't repair it, you have to throw it out.

Comment: @Robert - there always is a chance for repair... but admittedly it then may change a lot of the original's intent.